# Getting Sprite To Move Slowly Toward Touch

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to have the "player" sprite move slowly toward touches on the screen. The code that I have now moves the sprite immediately to where the touch happens on the screen. Here is my current code. Thanks!

```
    //
//  GameScene.swift
//  testing
//
//  Created by Matthew Jahnes on 7/3/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Matthew Jahnes. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var player = SKSpriteNode()


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)


        player = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 90, height:90))
        player.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
        self.addChild(player)


}
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        player.position.x = location.x
        player.position.y = location.y

    }
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. Create an action for moving the player to the destination point.
2. Stop the previous `move` action if exists
3. Run the new `move` action

Here's the code

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let destination = touch.location(in: self)
    let move = SKAction.move(to: destination, duration: 2)
    player.removeAction(forKey: "move")
    player.run(move, withKey: "move")
}
```

Comment: I would recommend a variable duration, otherwise your character is going to move at different speeds